# I can't add list in Class

Tags: python, class, oop, methods

Here my code. Its aim Bank application. We input User's accountNumber , name , balance. And application will do withdrawMoney , depositMoney , transferMoney. And I am trying to add AccountNumbers to List and i want use this list at transferMoney condition. Where and what should i add codes.

```
class BankAccount:

    def __init__(self,accountNumber,name,balance) -> None:
        self.accountNumber = accountNumber
        self.name = name
        self.balance = balance
        print(f"Sayın {self.name} {self.accountNumber} Numaralı Hesabınızda {self.balance} TL Bulunuyor.")

    def withdrawMoney(self,balance):
        if self.balance - balance < 0:
            print(f"Sayın {self.name} {self.accountNumber} Numaralı Hesabınızda Yeterli Para Bulunmuyor {self.balance - balance}")
        else:
            self.balance -= balance
            return f"Sayın {self.name} {self.accountNumber} Numaralı Hesaptan {balance} TL Çekildi ; Kalan Para {self.balance}"
            
    def depositMoney(self,balance):
        self.balance = balance + self.balance
        return f"Sayın {self.name} {self.accountNumber} Adlı Hesabınıza {balance} TL Yüklenmiştir. Toplam Para {self.balance}"
        
    def transferMoney(self,yourAccountNumber,aimAccountNumber,balance):
        if yourAccountNumber and aimAccountNumber in []: 
            yourAccountNumber.balance -= balance
            aimAccountNumber.balance += balance

            print(f"Sayın {self.name} {self.accountNumber} Adlı Hesabınızda {self.balance} TL Kalmıştır")
        else:
            print("Yanlış Hesap Numarası Girildi")

           

a1 = BankAccount(1234,"Ahmet",5000)

a2 = BankAccount(3456,"Kerem",8000)

print(a1.transferMoney(1234,3456,1000))
```

Comment: `transferMoney` shouldn't take account numbers, it should take a `BankAccount` object. It should do `self.withdrawMoney(balance)` then `otherAccount.depositMoney(balance)`

Comment: If you want to be able to look up accounts by number, you can have a class variable containing a dictionary that maps account numbers to `BanikAccount` objects. The `__init__()` method would add the account to the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Create a list to store account numbers: `allBankAccounts = []`

In the `init` append the account number to the list: `allBankAccounts.append(self.accountNumber)`

Pass the bank account objects into the transferMoney function (not account numbers). `a1.transferMoney(a2,1000)`

Your transferMoney func should look like this:

```
def transferMoney(self,a2,balance):
    yourAccountNumber = self.accountNumber
    aimAccountNumber = a2.accountNumber

    if yourAccountNumber and aimAccountNumber in allBankAccounts: 
        self.withdrawMoney(balance)
        a2.depositMoney(balance)

        print(f"Sayın {self.name} {self.accountNumber} Adlı Hesabınızda {self.balance} TL Kalmıştır")
        print(f"{a2.name} balance: {a2.balance}")
    else:
        print("Yanlış Hesap Numarası Girildi")
```

All code:

```
class BankAccount:

def __init__(self,accountNumber,name,balance) -> None:
    self.accountNumber = accountNumber
    self.name = name
    self.balance = balance
    allBankAccounts.append(self.accountNumber)
    print(f"Sayın {self.name} {self.accountNumber} Numaralı Hesabınızda {self.balance} TL Bulunuyor.")

def withdrawMoney(self,balance):
    if self.balance - balance < 0:
        print(f"Sayın {self.name} {self.accountNumber} Numaralı Hesabınızda Yeterli Para Bulunmuyor {self.balance - balance}")
    else:
        self.balance -= balance
        return f"Sayın {self.name} {self.accountNumber} Numaralı Hesaptan {balance} TL Çekildi ; Kalan Para {self.balance}"
        
def depositMoney(self,balance):
    self.balance = balance + self.balance
    return f"Sayın {self.name} {self.accountNumber} Adlı Hesabınıza {balance} TL Yüklenmiştir. Toplam Para {self.balance}"
    
def transferMoney(self,a2,balance):
    yourAccountNumber = self.accountNumber
    aimAccountNumber = a2.accountNumber

    if yourAccountNumber and aimAccountNumber in allBankAccounts: 
        self.withdrawMoney(balance)
        a2.depositMoney(balance)

        print(f"Sayın {self.name} {self.accountNumber} Adlı Hesabınızda {self.balance} TL Kalmıştır")
        print(f"{a2.name} balance: {a2.balance}")
    else:
        print("Yanlış Hesap Numarası Girildi")


allBankAccounts = []

a1 = BankAccount(1234,"Ahmet",5000)

a2 = BankAccount(3456,"Kerem",8000)

a1.transferMoney(a2,1000)
```

Comment: This is not correct: `if yourAccountNumber and aimAccountNumber in allBankAccounts:` It should be `if yourAccountNumebr in allBankAccounts and aimAccountNumber in allBackAccounts:`

Comment: I believe mine is fine

Comment: Your code is just checking of `yourAccountNumber` is not zero, it's not checking if it's in `allBankAccounts`.

Comment: Check the code mate, mine is correct

Comment: Try it with `a1 = BankAccount(0, "Ahmet", 5000)`

Comment: `TypeError: transferMoney() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given`  -> i think our TransferMoney functions are different

Comment: I said `BankAccount` not `transferMoney`

Comment: Oh my bad. Still that changes nothing because the `allBankAccounts.append(self.accountNumber)` will append the `0` as the new bank account

Comment: My point is that your `if` statement is just checking if `yourAccountNumber` is non-zero, it's not checking if it's in `allBankAccounts`.

Comment: Yes, if there was no `in` statements after the `and`. However, the `in` changes the functionality of the `and` to check inside the list

Comment: `in` doesn't distribute over `and`. It's parsed as `if yourAccountNumber and (aimAccountNumber in allBankAccounts):`

Comment: run this: `list = [1,2,3,4,5]

if 1 and 5 in list:
    print("true")
else:
    print("not true")`

Comment: That gets the expected answer by accident. Try it with `if 1 and 6 in list:`

Comment: i get `>not true` with `1 and 6`

Comment: Sorry, that was a bad example: `if 6 and 1 in list:`

Comment: oh ok interesting, that gave true

Comment: I stand corrected, thanks for letting me know

Comment: See [Operator Precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)